# Chapter Heading like this book, using memoir class

Tags: memoir

I would like to re-create the following style using the memoir class

[image]

I made a .cls file with

`\chapterstyle{veelo}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}`

and I get

[image]

Can you please tell me how I can modify the code to get the closest to the first picture? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First version**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}


% chapter style %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
\textcolor{gray}{\rule[7mm]{1.5cm}{4mm}}%
\hspace{-1.5cm}%
\rule[-3mm]{1.5cm}{2mm}%
}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}

% section style %%%%%%%%%%%

\setsecheadstyle{
\textcolor{gray}{\rule[4mm]{1.75cm}{2mm}}%
\hspace{-1.75cm}%
\rule[-2mm]{1.75cm}{1mm}%
\hspace{-1.75cm}%
\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries
}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Noise in oscillators}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second version**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}


% chapter style %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
\textcolor{gray}{\rule[7mm]{1.5cm}{4mm}}%
\hspace{-1.5cm}%
\rule[-3mm]{1.5cm}{2mm}
\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip
}

% section style %%%%%%%%%%%

\setsecheadstyle{
\textcolor{gray}{\rule[4mm]{1.75cm}{2mm}}%
\hspace{-1.75cm}%
\rule[-2mm]{1.75cm}{1mm}%
\hspace{-1.75cm}%
\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries
}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Noise in oscillators}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to make a mirrored version? (First the title and then the chapter number on the right side?)

Comment: @clidrevandijk answer updated